# Why did Orochimaru really want to destroy Konoha village in the Naruto series?

Tags: naruto

I started reading naruto manga again. In chapter 620, Sasuke ask Orochimaru, "I know the reason you told me to destroy Leaf Village was a lie. What was the real reason". And then, it strikes me that they never disclosed the real reason in future chapters, so does anyone know why Orochimaru attack Leaf Village?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I used to believe it was due to the fact that Hiruzen didn`t choose him to be hokage. And that was also why he returned to kill his master

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! We appreciate your contribution, but pure opinion/speculation answer is discouraged. Instead, please [edit] and try to back up the answer by providing supporting sources/references. Thank you.